# Cannot read property 'map' of undefined because reducer has problems

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I read there are many questions about this but I cant make this work.

I get this error because I think my `combineReducers` are set up wrong.
The List.jsx in the error dont get a hold of the `articles` map in the RootReducer.js

[image]

I have this configureStore.js

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { forbiddenWordsMiddleware } from "../middleware";
import  ToastsReducer from '../reducers/ToastsReducer';
import  RootReducer from '../reducers/RootReducer';

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const reducers = {
     Toasts: ToastsReducer,
     RootReducer: RootReducer
  };

  const reduce = combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
  });

const store = createStore(
    reduce,
    storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(forbiddenWordsMiddleware))
);
export default store;
```

and this is the reducers files

RootReducer.js

```
import { ADD_ARTICLE } from "../constants/action-types";
import { FOUND_BAD_WORD } from "../constants/action-types";

const initialState = {
  articles: []
};
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  if (action.type === ADD_ARTICLE) {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
    });
  }

  if (action.type === FOUND_BAD_WORD) {
    //return Object.assign({}, state, {
    //  articles: state.articles.concat(action.payload)
    // });
  }
  return state;
}
```

ToastsReducer.js

```
import { ADD_TOAST, REMOVE_TOAST } from "../constants/action-types";

export default function toasts(state = [], action) {
  const { payload, type } = action;

  switch (type) {
    case ADD_TOAST:
      return [payload, ...state];

    case REMOVE_TOAST:
      return state.filter(toast => toast.id !== payload);

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

List.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { articles: state.articles };
};
const ConnectedList = ({ articles }) => (
    <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
        {articles.map(el => (
            <li className="list-group-item" key={el.id}>
                {el.title}
            </li>
        ))}
    </ul>
);
const List = connect(mapStateToProps)(ConnectedList);
export default List;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are doing mapStateToProps wrongly. can you do something like this. I hope this helps.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return { articles: state.RootReducer.articles };
};
```